# UIImagePickerController with my images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm developing an app and I wish use the UIImagePickerController but I wish let the user to choose some images saved into my app, not the photolibrary.. it's possible to do this??
thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that that's not the way `UIImagePickerController` is designed, unfortunately. I've seen several projects have to reimplement this feature in their own (different) ways before moving forwards.

As a good first pass tutorial at this problem I would recommend [*this site*](http://www.raywenderlich.com/130/how-to-write-a-custom-image-picker-like-uiimagepicker)

It relies on a simple `UIScrollView` and custom views to do the job. I've also seen solutions to the problem that use custom `UITableView`s as well as a couple other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't. You can either select from the photo library or take a new picture. This is probably one of the most annoying things I've come across in the API. If you have to have this functionality, you will have to find an open source version or develop your own UIImagePickerController. I have used [this](http://blog.sallarp.com/shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation/) with some success.

Comment: thanks very much... and have you some info where to find some custom UIImagePickerController?
thanks

Comment: Yes - click on the "this" link in the last sentance of the answer :O)